# Fresh installation of Visual Studio 2017 is missing parts of F#

Tags: visual-studio-2015, f#, visual-studio-2017

I just did a fresh installation of Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 on a new computer, and loaded my solution into it. It now complains that it can't resolve `FSharp.Core 4.4.1.0` and indeed, it is not installed, despite I installed everything F# during the setup process. I have a `FSharp.Core 4.5.0.0` I can add to my projects as a reference, but in all my F# projects, I can only select F# 4.1, version 4.4.3.0 in the properties dialog which is not found either when compiling the project.

What am I missing? How do I get the missing F# stuff?

## Followup 1

I created a new solution and added a dll here. This creates a proper project which is set up and compiles fine. This links to F# Core 4.5.0.0 (which is fine), but I can't select any different version. Guess I'll have to manually re-create the solution and copy over all the source code.

## Followup 2

I recompiled the entire project, and surprisingly, all my EXEs work despite the compiler spits out tons of warnings that it can't resolve certain versions of FSharp.Core. So I'll have that going currently but I'll recreate the solution nevertheless.

## Followup 3

New F# projects get FSharp.Core from NuGet anyway, so recreation seems to be the way to go.

Comment: You can get other FSharp.Core versions via NuGet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mark it as solved, I post it as an answer.

The projects were started some time ago in VS 2015, that's why they didn't work correctly any more.

So, in case anyone else runs into this problem, here is what I did for each project:

1. Removed the `FSharp.Core` reference from the project in VS
2. Saved the project
3. Opened the according `fsproj` file in a text editor
4. Deleted the line that says `<TargetFSharpCoreVersion>4.4.1.0</TargetFSharpCoreVersion>`
5. Saved the file
6. Had VS reload the project
7. Issued in Package Manager Console: `Install-Package FSharp.Core -ProjectName TheProject`